# Getting an embedded YouTube video to play after it's been closed & re-opened on iOS7 Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios7, youtube, safari

Relatively new to JS here. I've created a button that embeds a YouTube video on the page when you click it, and the user has the ability to close it. On desktop and Android OS, it can be closed and re-opened as many times as the user wants. However, on iOS, the video only plays the first time.

I believe this issue is caused by the fact that Apple doesn't want the video to play without the user's permission, so when you click the "play" button it brings up the video - but the default YouTube play button itself is not there when the video is closed and re-opened.

This should be most of the relevant code.

```
    VideoPlayer = new VideoPlayer('Header', 'xi2-7FCuDdg');
    $("#HomePlayButton").on('click', function () {
        disable_scroll();
        VideoPlayer.play();
        $("#Header").append($('<a href="#" id="VideoCloseButton"><img src="/images/close.png" /></a>'));
        $("#VideoCloseButton").on('click', function () {
            VideoPlayer.stop();
            VideoPlayer.hide();
            enable_scroll();
            $("#VideoCloseButton").unbind('click');
            $("#VideoCloseButton").remove();
            return false;
        });
    });

    this.play = function () {
        if (!Initialized) {
            //  This autoplays the video
            Init();
            Initialized = true;
        } else {
            if ($("#" + YouTubeElementId).css('display') == "none") {
                $("#" + YouTubeElementId).css('display', 'block');
            }
            YouTubePlayer.playVideo();
        }
    }

    this.stop = function () {
        YouTubePlayer.stopVideo();
    }

    this.isPlaying = function () {
        return (Initialized) ? YouTubePlayer.getPlayerState() == 1 : false;
    }

    this.hide = function () {
        $("#" + YouTubeElementId).css('display', 'none');
    }

    this.show = function () {
        $("#" + YouTubeElementId).css('display', 'block');
    }
```

I'm assuming the easiest way to solve this would be to entirely destroy the iframe and make a new one every time the video is closed, but I was unable to successfully implement that.

Glad to post more code if it's necessary.

Comment: I don't know how related my experience is, but I recently worked an in-app YouTube player using the iFrame inside a UIWebView, we had some issues with the native controls no longer working once the video stopped playing at the end - especially in fullscreen. We chalked it up to an Apple bug in the media framework. We didn't try reloading the iFrame, but that would be my next line of attack when I go back to this code.